# how can I display images in carousel on the post

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I created a post that allows me to upload multiple image and the post contain title, description and image but im trying to be display in this template , but on every post are being displayed all photos not only the photos that have been upload for that post

here is my template code

```
{% for post in posts %}
<section class="container" style="margin-top: -0.8rem;">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div style="background-color: #000000" class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title" style="color: #FFFFFF; letter-spacing: 6px; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: -0.7rem;">{{ post.title }}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="{{ post.id }}" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          {% for p in photos %}
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}"></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          {% for p in photos %}
          <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}" style="background-color: #000000">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#{{ post.id }}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#{{ post.id }}" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #000000" class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="container" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align: justify; margin-top: -1rem;">{{post.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```

here is the models code -----------------------------

```
class Photo(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class PhotoImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Photo, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

And here is the View Code ----------------------------------

```
class PhotographyListView(ListView):
    model = Photo
    model = PhotoImage
    template_name = 'photography.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PhotographyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Photo.objects.order_by('-id')
        context['photos'] = PhotoImage.objects.filter()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template, only loop over the photos that are attached to the post.

```
{% for p in post.photoimage_set.all %}
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The PhotoImage query in the ListView wont be needed anylonger.

- To reduce extra queries, you might want to look up adding a `prefetch_related` to the `Photo.objects.order_by('-id')` query.

Comment: Can You Please Give me an example with my code becouse i tried and i cannot figure it out how to do it its not working

Comment: I updated the answer to allow for code formatting.
are you able to use the reverse_foreignkey look up? that is to say, get all photos that are attached to posts